# What could be making my Chrome extension cause intermittent "Aw Snap" errors on Google Search Pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that occasionally causes errors when searching on Google. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason as to when the errors will occur and whether they will be on-offs or strung together.

Sometimes the search will simply fail and bring the user to this URL...

```
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8
```

...with or without this console error...

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED       https://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/sdch=d/k=xjs.s.en_US.kcOorrX6BxU.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,jsa,r,hsm,j,p,d,csi/am=pET9LYYwKAXVhFAH/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oG82zdMYXRNPFJ62AyFQIkAFUm8XQ
```

Other times, the tab will get the "Aw Snap" error. Here is the relevant part of the log around the time of a crash:

```
[84526:35075:0423/140756:VERBOSE1:web_request_time_tracker.cc(177)] WR percent 6138: https://www.google.com/search?q=psycopg2._psycopg.cursor%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27commit&oq=psycopg2._psycopg.cursor%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27commit&aqs=chrome..69i57.111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8: 1/883 = 0.0018854
[84526:35075:0423/140756:VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(440)] OnReadCompleted: "https://www.google.com/search?q=psycopg2._psycopg.cursor%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27commit&oq=psycopg2._psycopg.cursor%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27commit&aqs=chrome..69i57.111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8" bytes_read = 0
[84526:35075:0423/140756:VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(784)] ResponseCompleted: https://www.google.com/search?q=psycopg2._psycopg.cursor%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27commit&oq=psycopg2._psycopg.cursor%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27commit&aqs=chrome..69i57.111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8
[84526:35075:0423/140756:VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(370)] OnResponseStarted: https://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/sdch=d/k=xjs.s.en_US.saLIBtdxS1s.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,jsa,r,hsm,j,p,d,csi/am=pCSE-FsMwiApqCaEOg/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oEMuE5jLV6RpZBKMp6fbqtiUf3IFw
[84526:35075:0423/140756:VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(440)] OnReadCompleted: "https://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/sdch=d/k=xjs.s.en_US.saLIBtdxS1s.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,jsa,r,hsm,j,p,d,csi/am=pCSE-FsMwiApqCaEOg/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oEMuE5jLV6RpZBKMp6fbqtiUf3IFw" bytes_read = 32768
<< Line above repeated ~30,000 times >>
[84526:35075:0423/140758:VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(440)] OnReadCompleted: "https://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/sdch=d/k=xjs.s.en_US.saLIBtdxS1s.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,jsa,r,hsm,j,p,d,csi/am=pCSE-FsMwiApqCaEOg/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oEMuE5jLV6RpZBKMp6fbqtiUf3IFw" bytes_read = 32768
[84532:15623:0423/140759:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(386)] Canceling pending sends
[84526:35075:0423/140759:VERBOSE1:web_request_time_tracker.cc(177)] WR percent 6142: https://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/sdch=d/k=xjs.s.en_US.saLIBtdxS1s.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,jsa,r,hsm,j,p,d,csi/am=pCSE-FsMwiApqCaEOg/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oEMuE5jLV6RpZBKMp6fbqtiUf3IFw: 1/2783 = 0.000402078
[84532:1299:0423/140759:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(386)] Canceling pending sends
[84532:15623:0423/140759:VERBOSE1:ipc_sync_channel.cc(386)] Canceling pending sends
```

---

Potential causes I've looked into:

- heavy flash use
- many tabs open
- script/ad/flash blockers
- heavy cpu/memory load both from Chrome and from other programs
- heavy network activity

Potential causes that I'm having trouble testing exhaustively:

- use of Angular.js
- chrome.tabs.executeScript

  - dynamically loading and eval'ing a script
- chrome.tabs.insertCSS
- chrome.tabs.sendMessage
- chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived (blocking)

  - changes CSP values
- chrome.storage.sync

I understand that some of the techniques in use are frowned upon. Trust me, if there were better ways to do what I need to do with this extension, I wouldn't be using said techniques.

Cheers, Alex

Comment: Why do you suspect an extension to be the cause?

Comment: That's actually a pretty good question. I personally have trouble repro'ing. However, coworkers have reported a higher frequency of errors while the extension is enabled -- once in a blue moon to once a day. When I say "once a day" I sometimes mean, "errors-repeatedly-until-restart once a day".

Comment: @Xan I have also faced a similar issue but could not find any appropriate reason. Clearing the cache seemed to resolve the issue for me but it was a but frustating as I myself didn't know how clearing the cache solved it. Check out https://github.com/blunderboy/requestly/issues/41 and https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa/support

Comment: Are you using Chrome Canary? I experienced this issue several times in v41 and above, even without particular extensions installed: just typing a search query through the omnibox and hitting Enter, sometimes Chrome fails to load the page and brings me to that same URL: `https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8`. I do not really know what could be causing this issue, but I suspect it's something about Chrome itself.

Comment: Marco none of those that have reported issues were using Canary.
Also, my local install is at 42.0.2311.90.

@Xan I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I've seen that error on a good number of machines in different locations. Also the file associated with the error should be a Chrome internal or at least a Google asset, no?